# How to store time picker into database [CLOSE]

Tags: php, android, mysql

Php code:

```
$odr_time = (isset($_POST['order_time'])) ? $_POST['order_time'] : "";


$Q_insert  = "INSERT INTO dsp_order_item SET order_time = '".$ord_time."';
```

Android:

```
 etTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(getContext(),
                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                  int minute) {

                                etTime.setText(String.format("%02d:%02d", hourOfDay, minute));
                                String order_time = etTime.getText().toString();
                            }
                        }, mHour, mMinute, false);
                timePickerDialog.show();
            }
        });
```

Previously, the DATE [SOLVED] and the TIME become empty where the field does not has any value. Is it because I set the data type 'VARCHAR' so it does not store it?

Any suggestion?

Comment: What happens when you run your app?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice smooth~

Comment: Use DATETIME  field in db to store the date time response from JSon

Comment: @PreetikaKaur but i need to separate it out like date: YYYY-MM-DD
time: HH:ii:ss

Datetime format is like: YYYY-MM-DD HH:ii:ss
right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you want to insert date to database, you can use this code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
String date = sdf.format(new Date());
```

In database insert the string 'date'

The date format in sqlite should be of following format:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.SSS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS
YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS.SSS
HH:MM
HH:MM:SS
HH:MM:SS.SSS
now
DDDDDDDDDD
```

For more details, have a look: http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: ya. i found the simpledateformat code but im not sure where to put the code in. Is in the php file or android file?
cause currently, im using datepickerdialog and timepickerdialog for date and time respectively.

Comment: That depends on your requirement.. Android side you can store it in these format and retrieve with your desire format with SimpleDateFormate function..And if you want to store it in php you can simply pass the string to your service and apply the same logic there

Answer (score 0):

thanks for helping and advising me to solve the problem. I had done this part by storing as DATETIME (Y-m-d, HH:MM:SS) which is easier. And I displayed it out separated by calling DATE and TIME using Y-m-d and H:m:s as what Arpit posted. Thanks.